# Positive sense of the $x$ axis

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, angle

[image]

Let's say we have a line $y=-x+2$, and we have to find the angle this line makes with the positive sense of the $x$-axis. I am unsure on which angle to take, alpha or beta. They are both angles of the positive side of the $x$ axis.

On the other hand, if a line $y=2$ was drawn then it would be clearer and would make angle B be the answer. However in this case I am unsure. A bit of clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would guess it is the angle $\beta$ that is meant, however this is ambiguous. What is the exact context of the question?

Comment: The line $y=2$ does not cross the $x$-axis, so it does not make any angle with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Positive sense" is a direction (to the right here). That's different from "positive side". So probably $\beta$.

I say "probably" because you need the sense of the line, too. $\beta$ is the answer if you assume the line goes up to the left - a counterclockwise rotation from the $x$-axis. If the sense of the line is down to the right then $\alpha$ is the angle.

The question really is ambiguous. The best kind of response starts with
"If by ... you mean ... then the answer is ...".